# upload a row to database table in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4

```
Use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    public function registerAStudent(Request $request)
{
    Student::Create($request->all());

}
```

I want to upload a row to the database table.
Form data is stored in the request variable and using **Student** model.
but can't update the database I'm getting following error:

> ErrorException (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR) HELP Argument 1 passed to
>   AdminController::registerAStudent() must be an instance of
>   Illuminate\Http\Request, none given

please give me a proper way to do it.

Comment: You need to inject StudentModel.... use Models\Student as Student and they try...

Comment: As the error clearly says that you are not passing `request` instance in your `registerAStudent` method. You have to show us how you are calling mentioned method.